# Can I change documentclass in the middle of a document?

Tags: document-classes

A school I'm applying to requires me to combine my research statement and my CV into a single document.  However, my research statement is in the `amsart` document class while my CV is in the `article` document class and I'm having trouble getting it to look at all nice in a single class.  Is there a way to change document class part of the way through a document?  Alternately is there an easy way to get LaTeX to just concatenate the output of two different files?

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33164/how-to-scale-entire-document-including-maths-symbols) for a detailed example of how to use `pdfpages`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you cannot change the document class in the middle of a document. One option would be to use the [pdfpages](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) package to include your CV in your research statement.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution would be to create two separate documents, and use a program like [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) to combine the two resulting pdfs.