# Using two latex classes simultaneously

Tags: document-classes

I have two latex classes and I would like to use them simultaneously. Let's say put title and cover pages from one class and rest of the context from the other one.

Comment: can't be done, i fear.

Comment: You can't do this.  But there are other methods.  See [Change documentclass per page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89792/2693) for one example.

Comment: You can't do that but you can see the source of any latex class, the implementation of maketitle is usually only a few lines of code so you can use the main class for your document settings and then copy the maketitle definition from the other class into your preamble.  (Some classes are easier than others to do this, it depends)

Comment: let us know if Alan Munn's link resolves this- if so, this can be closed as a duplicate :)

Comment: Also related, but probably less helpful in your case: [Can I change documentclass in the middle of a document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36463)