# Changing ALL spacing in a TeX document

Tags: spacing, line-spacing

I'm taking an exam and I'm allowed a two side page with information on it. Naturally I want to put as much as possible on it so:

What are all the spaces that I can change to fit as much information as possible on two pages? And how do you change them?

I.e. How do you change:

- line spacing
- text size
- margins
- space between bullet points
- space between equations
- etc.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/674/627

Comment: Was the paper size specified? If not, you might be interested in the document class [`a0poster`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/a0poster) :)

Comment: Also, note that you shouldn't use backticks / _accents graves_ `\`` as apostrophes, but actual apostrophes `'`, which you'll find on most keyboards as well. Particularly in LaTeX, the backticks might get you into trouble because they're often so-called active characters.

Comment: The teacher side of me thinks that you will not need all this extra information and you would be better off with a less dense "cheat sheet" that you can easily find things on.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I am sure there is no single package dedicated to the items you list, including "etc.", except perhaps [`savetrees`](http://ctan.org/pkg/savetrees):

> The goal of the `savetrees` package is to pack as much text as
> possible onto each page of a LaTeX document. Admittedly, this makes
> the document far less attractive. Nevertheless, `savetrees` is a
> simple way to save paper when printing draft copies of a document. It
> can also be useful when trying to meet a tight page-length requirement
> for a conference or journal submission.

On a case-by-case basis, the following might be of use:

- Line spacing:

Consider using the [`setspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace). Read more about adjusting the line spacing from the TeX FAQ entry: [Why doesn't `\linespread` work?](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-linespread)

- Text size:

Standard document class (like `article`, `book` and `report`) allow for passing optional arguments regarding the default font size. For example,

```
    \documentclass[10pt]{article}
```

will produce a document with default `10pt` font size. Other options include

```
    \usepackage{fix-cm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fix-cm
```

or

```
    \usepackage{anyfontsize}% http://ctan.org/pkg/anyfontsize
```

or using the [`memoir` document class](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) which allows font size selections from `9pt` to `60pt` by default.

- Margins:

[`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) is king when it comes to layout specification. For example,

```
    \usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
```

will leave a `1cm` margin (on all sides), without having to fiddle with other lengths.

- Space between bullet points:

In general, list management is easily made possible via [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem). For example, inter-item separation is set using

```
    \begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
      \item ...
      ...
    \end{itemize}
```

would leave no separation between items. The option `nosep` will kill all vertical spacing.

- Spacing between equations:

If you're referring to the spacing above/below equations in surrounding text, then you need to modify the lengths `\abovedisplayskip`, `\abovedisplayshortskip`, `\belowdisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayshortskip`. These lengths define the skip (and stretch/shrink) above and below an equation if the preceding/following paragraph has a short line or not.

If you're using [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `align` (and friends) environment, then the spacing between equations are usually set via the length `\jot`. Therefore, modifying this length would provide a tighter spacing between elements within that environment.

The above concepts both deal with vertical spacing. There's more options (like vertical spacing in `array` or `tabular`) contained within Herbert Voß' [`mathmode` document](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) (details will follow). Horizontal spacing is also something you can tighten within mathmode. For more on this, see the [`mathmode` document](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) (section **11 Space**, p 28).

Finally, you could also follow the approach in [How to scale entire document including Maths symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33179/5764) to compress a number of pages onto one using [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages)'s `nup` option. This would require a two-stage process of creating the regular information (phase 1), and then a compressed version via `pdfpages` (phase 2).

Comment: As well, if you have many bullets and such, you might consider using `twocolumn` option, because usually more text fits in two narrower columns than in one wide ;)

Answer (score 4):

Just as an addition to Werner's list: The [`extsizes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/extsizes) document classes (e.g. `extarticle`) allow for base font sizes `8pt` and `9pt`:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{extarticle}
```

This will adapt the respective sizes of titles etc. The margins still need to be dealt with via `geometry`.

As @tohecz suggested in his comment, using several columns might be helpful, as a really long line in tiny script won't be pleasant to read. Either use the `twocolumn` document class option or the [`multicol`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package.