# Condense Latex Title

Tags: formatting, titles

I wish for my Latex Title to be condensed so that it takes up less room on the page.

Here is my current source:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,ctable,booktabs}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                            
% Commands                                                                                                                                                                  
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                            
\newcommand{\justif}[2]{&{#1}&\text{#2}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\begin{document}
% --------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                            
% Start here                                                                                                                                                                
% --------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                            
\title{This is a title that need not take up half the page! (How do I fix this?)}%replace X with the appropriate number                                                     

 %if necessary, replace with your course title                                                                                                                              
\maketitle
This is the rest of my document...
\end{document}
```

1. How do I get the title to take up less space?

If you need more information let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which document class do you use, and which options do you use for the class?

Comment: I added that part of my source.

Comment: Related [How to fit the title into a single line?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100271/15717) and Linked Q

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can redefine `\@maketitle` as defined in `article.cls` and introduce some changes in skips, fonts, and any other elemnts you wish, to reduce the spacing reserved for the title. In the following example code I show one possible modification (original code is marked `%ORIGINAL` and lines changed, with `%NEW`); the showframe package was used to produce a frame to serve as a visual guideline:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  %\null%ORIGINAL
  %\vskip 2em%ORIGINAL
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\Large\@title \par}%ORIGINAL: \LARGE
    \vskip 0.3em%NEW
    %\vskip 1.5em%ORIGINAL
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 0.3em%NEW
    %\vskip 1em%ORIGINAL
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 0.5em%ORIGINAL
  %\vskip 1.5em%ORIGINAL
}
\makeatother
\title{This is a title that does not take up half the page! (You can introduce further modifications)}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
This is the rest of my document...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to not use `\maketitle`at all, and design your title from scratch according to your needed specifications.

Comment: What are the other options where you have comments that say original? Where can I find this information out?

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus I don't understand your first question; please explain in more detail. You can find the original definition in `article.cls`. Run `kpsewhich article.cls` in a terminal to see the path to this file in your system; typically `.../tex/latex/base/article.cls` (the dots represent part of the path that might vary depending on your LaTeX installation/OS).

Comment: For example you have: `{\Large\@title \par}%ORIGINAL: \LARGE` What other options can I use besides `\Large`?

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus any other font size switch: `\normalsize`, `\small`, `\footnotesize`,... or even something like`\fontsize{7}{8.4}\selectfont`, and you could also use `\itshape`, `\bfseries` ao any other font modification required.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `titling` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{titling}

\pretitle{\begin{center}\large}
\posttitle{\end{center}}
\preauthor{\begin{center}\normalsize}
\postauthor{\end{center}}
\predate{\begin{center}\footnotesize}
\postdate{\end{center}}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-40pt}

\begin{document}

\title{This is a title that need not take up half the page!
       (How do I fix this?)}
\author{A. U. Thor}

\maketitle

This is the rest of my document...

\end{document}
```

[image]