# How to decrease page margin of all side of page?

Tags: margins

Let us consider the following example :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
 \markboth{The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra}{}



The title of the book is a perfect way to synthesize the point of view of Vin-
cenzo Capasso (VK) about the role played by mathematics in nature and all
human activities, as mentioned by Willi J ̈ger in the Introduction. As VK
a
mentioned in one of his speeches, “it is important that our scientific com-
munity appreciates the importance of theory and mathematics to face the
enormous challenges which arise from the emerging fields of Biology and Medi-
cine, Industry and Economics to improve the quality of Life.” His enthusiasm
and new ideas have brought him in this challenging mission. By transferring
methods and tools from one field to another, by learning novel mathemat-
ical methods and ideas from the observation of real world phenomena and
behavior, and by approaching real industrial problems, he has accepted to
play a fundamental role in both the Italian and European community in the
establishment and reinforcement of communication channels between Acad-
emia (methods) and Industry (applications), being himself a driving force of
the scientific and technological progress that we are observing in our daily
life.


\end{document}
```

This produces :

[image]

But I'd like to produce the following output :

[image]

That is I want to decrease margin of left, right, top and bottom of page. How can I do this ?

Comment: `\usepackage[margin=.2cm]{geometry}`

Comment: The picture first one waste lot of space.So I want second.

Comment: It would appear that you've asked quite a few questions, and received answers to these questions, of late. However, it also looks like you haven't "accepted" -- by clicking on the green checkmark -- any of the answers you've received so far. Please consider accepting the answers to at least some of the questions you've posed; it's the preferred way to express one's appreciation for the time and effort fellow members of this site have put into answering your questions.

Comment: Related: [Redefining \maketitle to put a maximum of information in a page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72761/redefining-maketitle-to-put-a-maximum-of-information-in-a-page/72785#72785)

Answer (score 7):

The `geometry` package lets you manipulate nearly every page dimension in a very flexible variety of ways.  In particular, you can just say something like

```
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
```

to get quarter-inch margins all around.

Comment: I want to get the header and page number in the above picture.

Comment: With the `fancyhdr` package (http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) you can format header and footer as you wish. Please accept @BenLerner 's answer since it meets your needs. That's the best way to thank him.