# writing very dense filled document

Tags: spacing, minipage

I have to write a summary for a test on limited space (max 10 pages) so that I want to fill every space on the page. I thought of subdividing each page in different boxes, one box for each subtopic, but it should not be like a table, where cells in the same row have the same hight; instead, this should be individual. Also, it is important to write until the border of each cell having as **little white space as possible**.

I thought about using `minipage`, but I am not sure whether this is the right approach. What is the best possibility for this purpose and do you have any additional tipps on using **as much of the available space as possible**?

Comment: Use a very small font size, nearly no borders. `twocolumn` mode with very little column separation, etc.

Comment: You can additionally reduce the baselineskip. Be aware that at some point reading can become very hard.

Comment: @Skillmon Would you also recommend using minipage? Or just `twocolumn` / `multicolumn` instead?

Comment: The problem is, that using `minipage` you'd have to use a `minipage` for each column you're using anyway (else they can't start on different heights). But you could use `minipage`s in the columns of `twocolumn`/`multicolumn` to ensure there are no column breaks inside one content block.

Comment: Not sure is that is exactly what you want, but [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/72785/11604) have in mind a readable text in the minimal number of pages.