# How to customize header with Rmarkdown?

Tags: titles, r, rstudio

I'm currently working on a pdf document using `Rmarkdown` on `RStudio` but I'm very much confused about to how to customize my YAML section. This is my actual code:

```
---
title: "The very basics of R"
author: "Alejandro C."
date: "March, 2020"
output:
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: xelatex
    toc: true

mainfont: Times New Roman
fontsize: 12pt
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{titling}
  - \pretitle{\begin{flushleft}}
  - \posttitle{\end{flushleft}}  
  - \preauthor{\begin{flushleft}}
  - \postauthor{\end{flushleft}}  
  - \predate{\begin{flushleft}}
  - \postdate{\end{flushleft}}  

---
```

What I want to achieve is the following:

- Use a bigger fontsize in my title (for example, 14) and boldface it
- Use 12 fontsize for author and date
- Use 11 fontsize for my document (I don't know if this must be specified in the YAML section)

I'm new on this topic so I really don't know where to start besides the [R Markdown Reference Guide](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjr2ceQuqfnAhVSd6wKHU5cBHEQFjAAegQIBRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Frstudio.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F03%2Frmarkdown-reference.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2M4P5cwjjqyudM0DwsOy_W). Any help and advice will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You lost the format of each element of title forcing `flushleft` environments instead of redefining \maketitle, but some like ...

```
fontsize: 11pt
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{titling}
  - \pretitle{\begin{flushleft}\huge\bfseries}
  - \posttitle{\end{flushleft}}  
  - \preauthor{\begin{flushleft}\Large}
  - \postauthor{\end{flushleft}}  
  - \predate{\begin{flushleft}\large}
  - \postdate{\end{flushleft}}
```

... must be nearly to what you want. You can see what font sizes are exactly commands as `\large` or `\Large` [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24600/11604).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: By the way, where can I found some info about redifining \maketitle? As I said, this is a completely new topic for me but I'm eager to learn.

Comment: Simply is ``\makeatletter\def\@maketitle{<your definition >}\makeatotter``.  An example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/72785/11604). Alternatively, mostly in books,  you can use a ``titlepage` environment to construct yourself the  page title in a free format.  But instead of make elaborate YAML headers or add a lot of LaTeX code in the Rmarkdown body,  my advice is search about modify pandoc templates.