# Remove line break after section

Tags: spacing

When I write 
`\section{something}` on latex, it takes up a lot of space on the page, and has some whitespace above and below it. How do I remove said whitespace?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\section` is not defined in latex, it is defined in (most) document class files some provide parameters to adjust the spacing, some do not but packages such as titlesec  may be used to adjust it. But as you have shown no code it is hard to tell you what to change.

Comment: search  `% custom section`  in the code of example in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/72785/11604) to make a very compact document.  Said that, if your document is not only for your eyes, leave in peace the dawn vertical spaces, your readers will appreciate it !

Comment: I would suggest that you do not remove the whitespace. If you do it will look like poor typography. However if you have different spaces before and after several sections on a page try putting `\raggedbottom` in your preamble.