# Disabling enumeration for a document

Tags: equations, breqn, mathtools

I'd like to disable enumeration for my document. I'm using `amsmath` and `breqn`. I tried using `\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true}`, but it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true}
\begin{document}
\begin{dmath}
Q(\lambda,\hat{\lambda}) = -\frac{1}{2} P{(O \mid \lambda )} \sum_s \sum_m \sum_t             \gamma_m^{(s)} (t) \left( n \log(2 \pi ) + \log \left| C_m^{(s)} \right| + \left(    \mathbf{o}_t - \hat{\mu}_m^{(s)} \right) ^T C_m^{(s)-1} \left(\mathbf{o}_t -   \hat{\mu}_m^{(s)}\right) \right)
 \end{dmath}
 \begin{dmath}
Q(\lambda,\hat{\lambda}) = -\frac{1}{2} P{(O \mid \lambda )} \sum_s \sum_m \sum_t             \gamma_m^{(s)} (t) \left( n \log(2 \pi ) + \log \left| C_m^{(s)} \right| + \left(    \mathbf{o}_t - \hat{\mu}_m^{(s)} \right) ^T C_m^{(s)-1} \left(\mathbf{o}_t -   \hat{\mu}_m^{(s)}\right) \right)
 \end{dmath}
 \end{document}
```

I could use `dmath*`, but this is inconvenient, since I'm writing a formula sheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could redefine the `dmath` environment to be the `dmath*` environment, using

```
\renewenvironment{dmath}{\begin{dmath*}}{\end{dmath*}}
```

Here's a complete MWE that demonstrates the idea:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\renewenvironment{dmath}{\begin{dmath*}}{\end{dmath*}}

\begin{document}
\begin{dmath}
Q(\lambda,\hat{\lambda}) = -\frac{1}{2} P{(O \mid \lambda )} \sum_s \sum_m \sum_t             \gamma_m^{(s)} (t) \left( n \log(2 \pi ) + \log \left| C_m^{(s)} \right| + \left(    \mathbf{o}_t - \hat{\mu}_m^{(s)} \right) ^T C_m^{(s)-1} \left(\mathbf{o}_t -   \hat{\mu}_m^{(s)}\right) \right)
 \end{dmath}
 \begin{dmath}
Q(\lambda,\hat{\lambda}) = -\frac{1}{2} P{(O \mid \lambda )} \sum_s \sum_m \sum_t             \gamma_m^{(s)} (t) \left( n \log(2 \pi ) + \log \left| C_m^{(s)} \right| + \left(    \mathbf{o}_t - \hat{\mu}_m^{(s)} \right) ^T C_m^{(s)-1} \left(\mathbf{o}_t -   \hat{\mu}_m^{(s)}\right) \right)
 \end{dmath}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Great! This works for my purpose. Do you know if there is a way to make it work as it's done in mathtools: enumerate only those equations that are referenced?

Comment: @m33lky glad it works :) I don't know how to emulate the `mathtools` method; some study of `mathtools.sty` might help- I imagine it checks information from the `.aux` file, but beyond that I'm not sure