# Is there a package for concise notes?

Tags: notes

I'm thinking of creating concise pages of notes, mainly text, in the form of multiple layers of bullet points. Is there a package that I can give bullet pointed notes and it crams them as tightly on to a page as it can.

Thank you

Comment: perhaps useful: [How to scale entire document including Maths symbols?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33164)

Comment: Consider the [`savetrees`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/savetrees) and [`fullpage`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fullpage) packages which try to cram as much stuff onto a page as possible.

Answer (score 2):

From the LaTeX Wikibook:

> If you want tightly-packed lists, use the `mdwlist` package (included in the `mdwtools` bundle), which provides compact, "starred" versions of the previous environments, i.e. `itemize*`, `enumerate*` and `description*`. They work exactly in the same way, but the output is more compact. Other packages providing compacted lists are `paralist` and `enumitem`.
>   Alternatively, use the `memoir` class and with `\tightlists`.