# Condensing everything to force fit a page?

Tags: margins, fontsize

I have a math exam I can use three pages of notes for and I was thinking, 
is there a way to type a document in LaTeX that will auto adjust to fit three pages or should I just play with the font sizes and margins?

Comment: perhaps `pdfpages` as detailed in [How to scale entire document including Maths symbols?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33164)

Comment: Not exactly your issue but [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147545/how-do-i-ask-latex-to-exactly-fill-up-a-page) might help.